# Qt undefined reference to 3rdparty software libraries

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I using 3rd party library functions in my Qt application, but it's reporting errors such as "`undefined reference to bp_attach collect2 : error: ld returned 1 exit status`".

I have build 3rd party library (ion-dtn) from source code and did `make` & `make install`. I am certain that it has installed successfully in my Ubuntu system.

I have included its header file `"bp.h"` and Qt doesn’t complain about that. But when I compile I get the error mentioned above. Here is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MYUDP
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/
LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib

PKGCONFIG +=ion-d
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        myudp.cpp

HEADERS  += myudp.h

FORMS    += myudp.ui
```

Path of "bp.h" where bp_attach function is declared is `/usr/local/include/bp.h`.

Libs for 3rd party library are installed in `/usr/local/lib` and is defined in .pro.

Comment: But you only specify where the linker should find the library, you don't actually say what library to link with?

Comment: BTW, if your library does provide a `pkg-config` file, your `PKGCONFIG +=ion-d` might be useful to you - but only if you also specify `CONFIG+=link_pkgconfig`.

Comment: thanks Toby, I realise that it ion-d was typo and library doesnt provide pkg-config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have told QMake where to find the headers and the libraries, you need to specify *which* libraries need to be linked.  The QMake equivalent to `LDLIBS` is `LIBS`:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -lbp
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this will help:

```
LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib -l**You_library_Name**
```