# Getting "undefined reference to" when using the lib for ARM, but not when compiling it

Tags: linux, qt, shared-libraries, undefined-reference, .so

For one of my Qt Embedded projects I'm using a external Qt lib called SMTPEmail. This lib needs to be compiled before being included into a project, something that I managed to do *successfully* both for Qt 4.8 ARM and for Desktop.

The problem I'm getting is that when I include the headers into my project and include the library in the .pro, the linker gives me

```
(path_to_libs)/libSMTPEmail.so: undefined reference to `QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted(QString const&, unsigned short, QFlags<QIODevice::OpenModeFlag>)'
(path_to_libs)/libSMTPEmail.so: undefined reference to `QSslSocket::QSslSocket(QObject*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [re8k_interface-tgt] Error 1
```

but *only* for compiling for ARM. IOW compiling the lib for both ARM and Desktop goes OK, compiling the project for Desktop using the lib goes OK but compiling it for ARM using the lib goes wrong.

Following [this forum thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/29410-Mysterious-QSslSocket-error-causes-installation-to-fail-on-Ubuntu-64-bit) I suspected this could be due to missing the link to the library file of openssl (the project points to different lib folders when compiling for different environments). So I searched for all "openssl" related files inside the compiler for ARM (arm-arago-linux-gnueabi) and included in the same folder where the .so is located; same error. I then suspected the lib itself had other dependencies which were not in the path_to_libs, so I did a `readelf -d libSMTPEmail.so` and later in the `.so.1` and readelf did return some lib dependencies that were not inside the same folder of the library. I then copied all such dependencies to the folder and got no success either.

So what could be happening? All dependencies known by me were put in place and I still get the error only for the situation where the lib is included by another project compiled for ARM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point your QMake where your libs and header file is in your `.pro` file;

So find where your library is assume `/usr/local/include` then ;

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
```

Add which libs you will use;

```
LIBS += -lSMTPEmail
```

You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154253/qt-undefined-reference-to-3rdparty-software-libraries/34154895#34154895);

Comment: well I already do that - remember that I'm able to compile and link using Qt 4.8 for Desktop? It's just when I compile specifically for ARM that the problem appears with me already trying to add possible SMTPEmail's dependencies to it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things stand out for me in your question:

1.

> undefined reference to

This error message means that there was an error in the linking step of compilation. This occurs when you include a header to a function/class/variable but don't have the definition included in your own sources, or you do not link in a static library that does.

Searching for dependencies in libraries that are already compiled (.dll or .so) is too late, the compiler is looking for a static link, not a dynamic link.

2.

> compiling the lib for both ARM and Desktop goes OK, compiling the
>   project for Desktop using the lib goes OK but compiling it for ARM
>   using the lib goes wrong.

This suggests that you are using conditional compilation in your .pro file that does a "both" compilation, a "desktop only" compilation and a "ARM only" compilation. If this is correct, you need to examine your compilation instructions for your "ARM only" compilation.

---

The error message itself refers to you using two functions from the `QSslStock` class. These are part of the `QtNetwork` module so you should have the following in your .pro file in order for the necessary links to be formed.

```
Qt += network
```